# iOS system controls are increased in size

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, mvvmcross

I am developing a simple xamarin forms application with one view in conjunction with Mvvmcross framework. Everything was going well, but in some point of time, I have noticed that Status bar and all system controls like Alerts, Navigation Bar, Back Button are increased in size in comparison to other apps (only on iOS platform). I have tried, without success, to revert all changes, but this bug remains still. Other test application, created using VS 2015 template is working fine. At [Status bar size example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jSrRg.jpg) this difference is clearly visible.

In the code, I just have a standard Mvvmcross setup with MainPage.xaml view which contains a ContentPage without any custom effects or renderers.

iOS Setup.cs

```
protected override IMvxIosViewPresenter CreatePresenter()
            {
                Forms.Init();

                var xamarinFormsApp = new App();

                return new MvxFormsIosPagePresenter(Window, xamarinFormsApp);
            }
```

iOS AppDelegate

```
 [Register("AppDelegate")]
    public partial class AppDelegate : MvxApplicationDelegate
    {
        public override bool FinishedLaunching(UIApplication app, NSDictionary options)
        {

            var window = new UIWindow(UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds);

            var setup = new Setup(this, window);

            setup.Initialize();

            var startup = Mvx.Resolve<IMvxAppStart>();

            startup.Start();

            window.MakeKeyAndVisible();

            return true;
        }
    }
```

iOS Info.plist

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
  <dict>
    <key>CFBundleDisplayName</key>
    <string>XamarinFormsApp</string>
    <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
    <string>com.test.xamarintest</string>
    <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
    <string>1.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleIconFiles</key>
    <array />
    <key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
    <string>1.0</string>
    <key>LSRequiresIPhoneOS</key>
    <true/>
    <key>MinimumOSVersion</key>
    <string>9.0</string>
    <key>UIDeviceFamily</key>
    <array>
      <integer>1</integer>
    </array>
    <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations</key>
    <array>
      <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
    </array>
    <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations~ipad</key>
    <array>
      <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
      <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown</string>
      <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
      <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
    </array>
    <key>UIStatusBarHidden</key>
    <true/>      
  </dict>
</plist>
```

Comment: I've seen this happen a few times, but not sure what I did to cause it. Resetting the simulator (or hard rebooting the device I'm testing with), after terminating the app from the app switcher, seems to fix it. I think it's an accessibility feature that's being triggered.

Comment: Keith Rome, interesting consideration but, unfortunately, it doesn't explain why other apps are working correctly, no matter where they are launched: on a device or a simulator. Howeover, launching my app in simulator, rebooting the device or rebuilding app, gives no results.

Comment: The first thing that comes to mind it; isn't it running in compatibility mode? This is determined by adding the right splash screen size, for instance see [this link](http://redth.codes/get-your-monotouch-apps-ready-for-iphone-5-ios-6-today/) although it seems unlikely this is the problem nowadays as all templates should be updated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the problem. The reason, why this had happened, is that I used splash screen still images instead of storyboard approach. I do not understand why iOS doing such controls size scaling but the solution is to remove that images and use storyboard approach for launch screens.

P.S. Thanks to Gerald Versluis reply. It has guided me in the right direction.